# Netbeans spell checker doesn't work with comments

Tags: netbeans

How to set up netbeans spell checker for PHPDoc comments as

```
/**
 * Comment
 */
```

and

```
// comment
```

?

If I write string outside `<?php ... ?>`, then spell checker works.

Answer (score 3):

The Netbeans Spell checker does not support the comments so you cannot do that with the current version around.

Maybe you can find another plugin?

Comment: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/3906/spellchecker -->
 This module allows spellchecking of Javadoc comments, Ruby comments, HTML/XML and versioning commit messages. Correcting misspelled words is also supported through editor hints. Place the caret into the misspelled word and press Alt-Enter. The hints also allow to add the word into a project-specific dictionary or into a user's private dictionary

Answer (score 3):

This is currently proposed as an enhancement [at the Netbeans issue tracker](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=189814), but isn't still addressed.

You can vote it there, for improving it's priority.

Comment: According to the bugtracker the [issue](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=189814) is fixed now.